# RowFilter sorting

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataview

I have `DataView` `RowFilter` calling on `textBox1_TextChanged`.

Code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
     DataView dv = new DataView(table);
     if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
     { 
         dv.RowFilter = "Price =" + textBox1.Text;
     }
}
```

Sometimes this work but in last time I recive this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String
>   and System.Int32.

Also I try to sorting column `Price` from larger number to lowest. What is best way to do that?

Comment: What is the type of `Price`? Maybe you need `"Price =" + int.Parse(textBox1.Text)`?

Comment: It's `int` I try it but don't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this code and dont pass blank value, pass 0 default value.

```
  var s = "8";
    dv.RowFilter = "price = "+ s;
```

But I have tried your code. your getting error because price column is not in View.